# how to use python to produce a group of anagram with a given list

Tags: python

for example :giving a list

```
['car','bed','stop','pots','arc','tops','z','z','rac','deb']
```

then with the function: produce

```
[['arc', 'car', 'rac'], ['bed', 'deb'], ['pots', 'stop', 'tops'], ['z', 'z']]
```

Comment: Results must be english words or can be anything?

Comment: Try to do it yourself, then come back and ask a specific question about your attempt, posting code if possible. And if this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: @Lily: We generally don't write code for people.  If you make an honest attempt and post what you come up with, we could give you pointers, and steer you in the right direction though

Comment: Probaby is homework http://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs234/a5/prog.html

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be taken from [this assigment](http://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs234/a5/prog.html), but the OP doesn't specify the "no builtin sort constraint, so...

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d=defaultdict(list)
>>> words = ['car','bed','stop','pots','arc','tops','z','z','rac','deb']
>>> for w in words:
...   d[''.join(sorted(w)].append(w)
... 
>>> d.values()
[['bed', 'deb'], ['car', 'arc', 'rac'], ['z', 'z'], ['stop', 'pots', 'tops']]
```

Comment: broken for general case ('stop' and 'stoop' will be reported as anagrams)

Comment: you could use sort(w) instead

Comment: @wim, good point. My original version used ''.join(sorted(w)) which doesn't have that problem, but looks like the OP isn't allowed to use builtin sort for the homework. I'll change it back

Comment: I do not defaultdict function

Comment: def anagram(a,b):
  for letter in a:
    if letter in b:
      b=b.replace(letter,"")
    else:
      return False
    return True
    
def find(alst): 
  l = [] 
  for i in range(0,(len(alst)-1)): 
    for j in range (0,(len(alst)-1)):
      while anagram(alst[i],alst[j]):
 l=l.append[i]
      return l
  this is my code, i do not know what wrong with my code